# Converting Tensor to np.array using K.eval() in Keras returns InvalidArgumentError

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

This is to define a custom loss function in Keras. The code is as follows:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.optimizers import Adam

def custom_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    a_numpy_y_true_array = K.eval(y_true)
    a_numpy_y_pred_array = K.eval(y_pred)

    # some million dollar worth custom loss that needs numpy arrays to be added here...

    return K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)


def build_model():
    model= Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(16, input_shape=(701, ), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss=custom_loss_function, optimizer=Adam(lr=0.005), metrics=['accuracy'])  
    return model

model = build_model()
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=1) 
model.fit(kpca_X, y, epochs=50, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_stop], verbose=False)
```

The above code returns following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\milind.dalvi\personal\_python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1326     try:
-> 1327       return fn(*args)
   1328     except errors.OpError as e:

D:\milind.dalvi\personal\_python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1305                                    feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1306                                    status, run_metadata)
   1307 

D:\milind.dalvi\personal\_python\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     88             try:
---> 89                 next(self.gen)
     90             except StopIteration:

D:\milind.dalvi\personal\_python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    465           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 466           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    467   finally:

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dense_84_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?]
     [[Node: dense_84_target = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

So anybody knows how we could convert `y_true` and `y_pred` which is `Tensor("dense_84_target:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=float32)` into numpy array

**EDIT:**
**--------------------------------------------------------**

Basically what I expect to write in loss function is something as follows:

```
def custom_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):

    classifieds = []
    for actual, predicted in zip(y_true, y_pred):
        if predicted == 1:
            classifieds.append(actual)
    classification_score = abs(classifieds.count(0) - classifieds.count(1))

    return SOME_MAGIC_FUNCTION_TO_CONVERT_INT_TO_TENSOR(classification_score)
```

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know whether it could help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The loss function is compiled with the model. At compile time, `y_true` and `y_pred` are only placeholder tensors, so they do not have a value yet and can therefore not be evaluated. This is why you get the error message.

Your loss function should use Keras tensors, not the numpy arrays they evaluate to. If you need to use additional numpy arrays, convert them to tensors via the `variable` method of `keras.backend` ([Keras Backend Documentation](https://keras.io/backend/)).

**Edit:**

You will still need to stay inside the Keras function space to make your loss work. If this is the concrete loss function that you want to implement, and assuming that your values are in {0,1}, you can try something like this:

```
import keras.backend as K

def custom_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):

    y_true = y_true*2 - K.ones_like(y_true) # re-codes values of y_true from {0,1} to {-1,+1}
    y_true = y_true*y_pred # makes the values that you are not interested in equal to zero
    classification_score = K.abs(K.sum(y_true))
```

Comment: Your answer is definitely helpful and hence I would upvote it, but I am not looking for external numpy arrays to K.variable conversion. I have updated the EDIT to clarify what I am seeking for!

Answer (score 0):

> So anybody knows how we could convert y_true and y_pred which is Tensor("dense_84_target:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=float32) into numpy array

```
the_tensor = K.arange(5)
// >>> Tensor("arange:0", shape=(5,), dtype=int32)
the_np = the_tensor.eval(session=K.get_session())
// >>> [0 1 2 3 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You convert the tensorflow TENSOR into NUMPY ARRAY in the 4 steps (1-4):
2. You convert the INT or FLOAT into the tensorflow TENSOR in the 2 steps (A-B):
3. In my opinion it is recomended to use dtype='float' not dtype='int'. In my model loss int doesn't work.
4. You create a custom loss function in Keras like this.
5. A converting tensorflow tensor into a python list makes it easier to use for a pythoneer.

```
#STEP1 IMPORT TENSORFLOW AND KERAS LOSS
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.losses import Loss

#TO MAKE YOUR LOSS FUNCTION WORK YOU MUST DEFINE A CALL FUNCTION IN A CLASS INHERITING FROM KERAS LOSS CLASS
class yourLoss (Loss):
    def __init__ (self):
        super().__init__()
    def call (self, y_true, y_pred):
        #STEP_A: MAKE A VARIABLE HOLDING YOUR MODEL TENSOR PARAMETERS
        #MULTIPLYINIG IT BUT 0 MAKES IT EMPTY 
        shapeHolder = y_pred * 0

        #STEP3 CAST YOUR TENSOR
        y_true = tf.cast (y_true, dtype='float')
        y_pred = tf.cast (y_pred, dtype='float')

        #STEP4 CONVERT IT TO NUMPY ARRAY
        y_pred = y_pred.numpy ()
        y_true = y_true.numpy ()

        #YOU CAN CONVERT A TENSOR INTO PYTHON LIST AS WELL
        #YOU CAN WRITE THE STEPS IN ONE CODE LINE
        y_true = tf.cast (y_true, dtype='float').numpy ().tolist ()
        y_pred = tf.cast (y_pred, dtype='float').numpy ().tolist ()

        #loss = your loss function

        #STEP_B: CONVERT THE INTEGER LOSS TO THE WANTED TENSOR
        #ADDING AN INT TO ZERO TENSOR MAKES ALL TENSOR NUMBERS THE INT
        #BUT I THINK IT'S BETTER TO USE FLOAT NOT INT 
        return shapeHolder + loss

#STEP2 TURN ON TRACING
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly (True)
model.fit (....)

#IT IS RECOMENDED TO TURN IT OFF LATER, A TRACING IS EXPENSIVE
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly (False)
```